# use of by that in a sentence

Tags: meaning

is the following sentence grammatically correct?

> India has conveyed its strong protest to Pakistan over an order by that country’s supreme court allowing the conduct of general elections in Gilgit-Baltistan.

I think it is not.

Comment: What do you think is wrong with the use of *by that*?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is grammatical. The issue is "an order by Pakistan's supreme court". Rather than repeat the word "Pakistan", they used the phrase "that country". So, it's not "an order by that" but "an order by [that country's supreme court]".